# MySql Service is not running in Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, xampp

I am trying to run xampp on linux through terminal, but mysql database is not running

after running the command to start Xampp server I get following output

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.0.2-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
root@kali:/opt/lampp# /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process
```

Upon checking the mysql status I get this output

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

How should I resolve it?

Comment: So what does your mysql log file say what the issue is?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba or serverfault sister sites of SO offer help in database admin or server management type of questions respectively. Depending on the exact issue, your question will fall into one of the two sites.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this learning may i know where i can get this file in lampp folder? @arkascha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638128/where-can-i-find-the-mysql-log-file-in-xampp